# Read an unknown number of lines from console in c++

Tags: c++, string, input, iostream

I am using the following loop to read an unknown number of lines from the console, but it is not working. After I have fed the input I keeping pressing enter but the loop does not stop.

```
vector<string> file;    
string line;
while(getline(cin,line)
    file.push_back(line);
```

Comment: how do you want to know when to stop collecting?

Comment: You need to use a special character, or keyword that your program waits for. When that is entered then you can stop collecting lines.

Comment: There's a difference between "an empty line" and "no line".

Answer (score 8):

Because `getline` will evaluate to true even if you push only enter.

You need to compare the read `string` to the empty string and break if true.

```
vector<string> file;    
string line;
while(getline(cin,line))
{
    if (line.empty())
       break;
    file.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: Comparing to newline isn't necessary because it won't ever occur, since getline() strips the delimeter from its return: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Can you please help me? though I used the same code, when I gave just enter, it is not coming out of the loop.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan That while loop will stop only when it'll read an empty line, so you need to press enter two times because you need to feed the input with a blank line (I'm sure you've figured it out int this time :) but it's for future readers)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vector<string> file;    
string line;
while( getline(cin,line))
{
    if( line.empty())
        break;
    file.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `getline` is easy, as it is suggested by other answers:

```
string line;
while(getline(cin,line))
{
    if (line.empty())
       break;
    file.push_back(line);
}
```

But to `cin objects`, **I found a way to without the need for any breaking character**. You have to use the same variable to cin all of the objects. After usage, you need to set it to a default exit value. Then check if your variable is the same after the next cin. Example:

```
string o;
while(true){
    cin>>o;
    if (o.compare("tmp")==0)
        break;
    // your normal code
    o="tmp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should signal the end of file to your application. On Linux it is Ctrl-D, and it might be Ctrl-Z on some Microsoft systems

And your application should test of end of file condition using `eof()`

Comment: The question is not about reading form files, but from the console.

Comment: @Luchian: I disagree. I think Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z is what the OP is looking for. However, I think the `eof()` advice is off. I'd vote up if it weren't for that.

Comment: "After I have fed the input I keeping pressing enter but the loop does not stop." - I think he's looking for a solution where the loop exits on pressing the enter key; I find it pretty clear.