# read unknown numebr of lines c++

Tags: c++, input

I got the answer for my question from [Read an unknown number of lines from console in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980985/read-an-unknown-number-of-lines-from-console-in-c) . But still, the solution is not working for me. please help me. This is the complete code I have implemented for certain question. the first block of it is the code to read multiple lines.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      vector<int> numbers;
      string line;
      int num = 0,rem = 0,count=0;
      while(getline(cin,line))
      {
       if(line.empty())
       {
//      cout<<"line check successful"<<endl;
        break;
       }
       numbers.push_back(atoi(line.c_str()));
      }
      cout<<endl;
      for(int i =0;i<numbers.size();i++)
      {
      num = numbers[i];
      for(int j=1;j<=num;j++)
      {
        while(j)
        {
            rem = j % 10;
            if(rem != 3 || rem !=7 || rem!=9)
            {
                j = j/10;
                continue;
            }
            count ++;
            j = j/10;
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    count = 0;
}
```

}

The first part of it is the algo to read unknown no.of lines. However, upon an empty return or by pressing just enter without any input, the loop is not stopping. Can you please point out where am going wrong.? thanks in advance.

Comment: the title has nothing to do with the question, check your math to get rid of the infinite loop

Comment: Did you debug your code? Print some variables.

Comment: @yngum Please check the first block. that is where am reading the lines from input, from console. That infinite loop has to stop wen am giving an enter. I hope am clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
for(int j=1;j<=num;j++)
{
  while(j)
```

The while loop doesn't stop until j is 0, and then it goes to the for loop and increments j, so j is now 1, but the while loop runs again until j is 0, so you loop forever.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. But my problem is even before that. The while loop above that. That loop is not exiting.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan: And how do you know it isn't exiting?

Comment: that cout statement inside the if did not execute. thats why I had commented it. For some reason, I tried it again now and it worked. Yes the problem you pointed out is correct.Thank you.