# How to accept an unknown number of lines in c++, each line has two strings

Tags: c++, input, cin, stdstring

How do I accept an unknown number of lines in c++? Each line has two strings in it separated by a space. I tried the solutions mentioned in [This cplusplus forum](https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/52566/), but none of the solutions worked for me. One of the solutions works only when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed at the end of each line. I am not sure if the `\n` char will be given at the end of my input lines. What are my options?

My current attempt requires me to press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to end the lines.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line; 
    while(cin>>line and cin.eof()==false){
        cout<<line<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to take an unknown number of strings as shown below:

```
cool toolbox
aaa bb
aabaa babbaab
```

Please don't flag this as a duplicate, I really tried all I could find! I tried the following solution on the above given link by m4ster r0shi (2201), but it did not work for me.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;

    string word;
    string line;

    // get the whole line ...
    getline(cin, line);

    // ... then use it to create
    // a istringstream object ...
    istringstream buffer(line);

    // ... and then use that istringstream
    // object the way you would use cin
    while (buffer >> word) words.push_back(word);

    cout << "\nyour words are:\n\n";

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        cout << words[i] << endl;
}
```

And this other solution also did not work: [other soln](https://cpp.sh/), and I tried this SO post too: [Answers to similar ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980985/). This one worked for my example, but when I pass only one line of input, it freezes.

```cpp
// doesn't work for single line input 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line ="-1"; 
    vector<string>data;
    while(1){
        cin>>line;
        if(line.compare("-1")==0) break;
        data.push_back(line);
        line = "-1";
    }
    for(int i =0;i<data.size();i+=2){
        cout<<data[i]<<' '<<data[i+1]<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your input? Not having a newline between lines doesn't make a lot of sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each line has two words separated by whitespace, then perhaps you should have a `Line` struct which contains two `std::string`s and overloads the `>>` operator for `std::istream`.

Then you can just copy from `std::cin` into the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Line {
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& i, Line& line) {
    return i >> line.first >> line.second;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Line> lines;

    std::copy(
      std::istream_iterator<Line>(std::cin),
      std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
      std::back_inserter(lines)
    );

    for (auto &[f, s] : lines) {
        std::cout << f << ", " << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A test run:

```
% ./a.out                
jkdgh kfk
dfgk 56
jkdgh, kfk
dfgk, 56
```